# What are java object fields initialized with?

Tags: java, initialization

Is it `null` for `Object` type?

```
class C {
    int i;
    String s;
    public C() {}
}
```

Will `s` be always `null`?

What about simple types as `int`? What will that be? Zero or an arbitrary value?

What about local variables in methods?

```
public void meth() {
    int i;
}
```

What is the unitialized value of `i`?

---

> Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad
>   programming style.

Ok, what do you suggest we do?

```
class A {
    String s = "";
    int i = 0;
}
```

OR:

```
class A {
    String s;
    int i;
    public A() {
        // default constructor
        s = "";
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 33):

From suns [java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> It's not always necessary to assign a
>   value when a field is declared. Fields
>   that are declared but not initialized
>   will be set to a reasonable default by
>   the compiler. Generally speaking, this
>   default will be zero or null,
>   depending on the data type. Relying on
>   such default values, however, is
>   generally considered bad programming
>   style.
>
> The following chart summarizes the
>   default values for the above data
>   types.

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte                    0 
short                   0   
int                     0 
long                    0L 
float                   0.0f 
double                  0.0d 
char                    '\u0000' 
boolean                 false
String (or any object)  null
```

> Local variables are slightly
>   different; the compiler never assigns
>   a default value to an uninitialized
>   local variable. If you cannot
>   initialize your local variable where
>   it is declared, make sure to assign it
>   a value before you attempt to use it.
>   Accessing an uninitialized local
>   variable will result in a compile-time
>   error.

Answer (score 4):

For member variables:
The default value for String is null. The default value for primitives is 0 (or 0.0 for floating point values).

For local variables:
You must explicitly initialise a local variable before using it.

As to the second part of your question:
You can always say `String s = "";` in the member variable definition, or `s = "";` in the constructor. Then you know it will have a non-null value. (Also, in your setter you'd need to ensure that someone doesn't try and set it back to null.)

Comment: <<Also, in your setter you'd need to ensure that someone doesn't try and set it back to null>>
Tons and tons of stupid work. Of course I can do that. But that's not what I'm expecting of programming style. Suppose you have to do that for 1000 fields.

Comment: What's with the attitude? That's all you've got in Java without relying on either a third-party library (as per nd's Google Collections answer) or writing a "check for null" method yourself (or using AOP or byte code manipulation or some other nefarious manipulation).

Comment: @Ash. Thank you for your answer & comments. Google Collections look very interesting. It's worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

**Fields:** Objects default to null; ints, longs and shorts to 0; Strings to null; booleans to false. It's all [**here**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

The compiler will force you to initialise variables declared in methods, **local variables**,  yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive fields are initialized to `0` / `false`. Objects are initialized to `null` . But frankly, you could have tried that one..

Comment: .. although trying only makes sense if you're sure, field initialization is defined and reliable. Sure, we know, it is, and that the compiler won't let you go where it isn't (local variables). But if you're not sure and don't know where to look, then it's worth both a question and a good answer (BTW, +1).

Comment: ->frankly, you could have tried that one.
It may be A NON REPEATABLE TEST. You can get 0 a thousand times. And then, get 4 billions as memory got refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

As for the setter-method question: The whole point of setters is that they can check if the object passed conforms to the requirements of the class. e.g.

```
public void setS(String s) {
  if (s == null)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("S must not be null");
  this.s = s;
}
```

Or, with Google Collections/Google Guava:

```
public void setS(String s) {
  this.s = Preconditions.checkNotNull(s, "S must not be null");
}
```

Of course, you can define arbitrary constraints, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Sets the foo. Legal foo strings must have a length of exactly 3 characters.
 */
public void setFoo(String foo) {
  if (foo == null)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Foo must not be null");
  if (foo.length() != 3)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Foo must have exactly 3 characters");
  ...
```

Of course in such a case you should *always* state the correct range of values for your properties in the JavaDoc of the setter and/or of the class.

Comment: well, preconditions.checknotnull looks very Pretty !!
why is it not in standart java library? that's what I'm expecting from Java.

Answer (score 0):

[JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (byte)0.
>
> For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (short)0.
>
> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>
> For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>
> For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>
> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
>   '\u0000'.
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.
>
> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.