# Are all fields of a static class assigned default values?

Tags: java

Consider the following class:

```
public class Main {
  private int x1;
  public static int x2;

  static class A {
    private int x3;
    static private int x4;

    class B {
      void f() {
        System.out.println( ? x ? )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The question was:

> Which of {x1,x1,x3,x4} can be written in place of ?x? for the class to compile?

At first I thought that only x2 and x4 would work, as they are static data members of their containing classes and as such, they are kept on the heap and assigned a default value of 0, so accessing them should compile fine. However, the right answer was x2, x4 and x3. My question is, was x3 assigned a default value as well, being a member of a static class? What is the rule for these cases?

Comment: All fields *period* are assigned default values, static or not.

Comment: All fields are assigned their default value (`null`, 0, `'\0'`, `false`, etc.) when their class is initialized (for static fields) or when their instance is initialized. It is irrelevant for determined which fields can be accessed in method `Main.A.B.f()`

Comment: To be best of my knowledge this is true for reference types, here we have a primitive type field

Comment: The best of your knowledge is wrong. It is true for primitive fields, although the default value will be different and not `null` since that has no meaning for primitives.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [What are java object fields initialized with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913168/what-are-java-object-fields-initialized-with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the member variables are assigned a default value. If your actual question is, why does the code compile when `x3` is inserted in the print statement, that's because `class B` is an inner class to `class A`. So `class A`'s fields are accessible inside `class B`, regardless of whether `class A` is a static class or not.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, was x3 assigned a default value as well

Yes. Instance variables (aka fields) are assigned default values when an instance is created. This is true regardless of what kind of class the class is. It isn't related to `A` being a static nested class.

It happens here, too:

```
public class Example {
    private int x;
    void f() {
        System.out.println(this.x); // 0
    }
}
```

The only reason `x1` wasn't a valid option is that it's an instance variable in `Main`, and `B.f` doesn't have any instance of `Main` to access `x1` on. Code in `B` has an implicit reference to the `A` instance it's a part of (`B` is an inner class), but `A` doesn't have an implicit reference to any instance of `Main`, because it's not an inner class, it's a static nested class. If you passed an instance of `Main` into code in `A` or `B`, it would have access to that instance's `x1`, but it needs an explicit instance of `Main`, there's no implicit one.

Comment: Not sure I understand. When was an instance of class A created?

Comment: @Noa: In code not shown, otherwise `B.f` could never be called (since `B` is a nested class). In order to call `B.f`, an instance of `A` must exist.