# In java how main class array allocation and main method array allocation?

Tags: java, arrays

how int arr[] gets null and how main method a[] gets error

```
      public class Main
      {
       int arr[];
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
        int a[];
        Main m=new Main();
    
       System.out.println("Main class array"+m.arr); //null
       System.out.println("Main method array"+a);   //error
       }
     }
```

Comment: You never initialize `m.arr` so, being an instance member, it gets a default value of `null`, and you never initialize `a` so, being a local variable, it's a compile-time error.

Comment: *Member* variables, which are variables defined in a class, such as `arr` in your example, are initialized to `null` by default. But *local* variables, which are variables defined inside a method, such as `a`, are not initialized at all by default. You must initialize them explicitly, otherwise the compiler will complain that you're trying to use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Good reads: [What are java object fields initialized with?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913168/5515060) and [Variable default value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9687634/5515060)